# add header to WebHeaderCollection in POST method windows phone 7

Tags: http-post, windows-phone-7, request-headers

My server requires us to post a header that include device ID to server, normally we can do some thing like this:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_connectionURL);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        request.Headers.Add    // THIS METHOD DOESN'T EXIST in windows phone 7
        request.Method = "POST";
```

It has this method, which allows you to set available headers, but the header I want is not included there, how can I add another header to WebHeaderCollection.

```
request.Headers.AllKeys.SetValue //this function to set the available headers.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
request.Headers["MyHeaderName"] = "MyHeaderValue";
```

Some headers are restricted, such as Referrer, and will throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply :D