# Is there a way to send a Content-Type header in a GET request on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can I send a Content-Type header in a Windows Phone 8 GET request?

I have to use a web service provided by our client that requires consumers to send a `Content-Type` header even with `GET` requests. Is there a way to achieve this?

I've tried using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` and `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` (which is also used by `System.Net.WebClient`).

HttpClient throws the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.
```

WebClient throw the following exception:

```
System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.  
---> System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: A request with this method cannot have a request body.
```

Actually, I fully agree with the exceptions, but I really need to access the APIs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116166/add-header-to-webheadercollection-in-post-method-windows-phone-7

Comment: @kshitijgandhi Not relevant to my problem at all. Except maybe for the hint that some headers are restricted and throw an exception. But I know that already.

Answer (score -2):

For HttpWebRequest you can use

```
webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(<yourUri>);
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype(v=vs.110).aspx for more details (example uses POST) on how to use it with HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Yes, I am using this in inside my productive code. The only difference is, that the Method and ContentTypes are defined via Method parameter.

Comment: I just tried it once more (because I've tried it already, see my question), it doesn't work. What version of windows phone are you developing for?

Comment: WP8. I did not yet migrate the project to WP8.1 because the customers do not have 8.1 completely :-) - and have you compared it with the details of the link which I attached? I had no issues so far with HttpWebRequest -> even better, it is part of my portable class library to support Win8 + Win Phone 8 with one code base for connectivity.